# How do you use an image in css and show that image by document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

```
#maze{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 1%;
    width: 730px;
    background-image: url("maze.jpg");}   //these are in the css.

var maze = document.getElementById('maze');  //this line is in the script.

<div id = "maze"></div>  //this line is in the body.
```

I am trying to use document.getElementById to show the images.
I used `background-image: url("maze.jpg");` to let the code show the image but it did not work. Can anyone tell me what I can fix?

Thank you!

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you try to do with the Javascript, but assuming the filename is correct, the image doesn't show because `.` is a class selector and the div has an id. So either `#maze` in the CSS or `<div class="maze">` in the HTML (but not both).

Comment: I did it but still doesn't work..

Comment: What's the point of your JS? Your html/css will show the image. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make a maze, and a girl picture has to find the right way using arrow key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i understand you correctly you want the js file to change the css of your div right? If so try this instead in your js file.

```
document.getElementById("maze").style.backgroundImage = "url(maze.jpg)";
    document.getElementById("maze").style.width = "732px";
     document.getElementById("maze").style.top = "25%";
      document.getElementById("maze").style.right =  "1%";
```

What this do is it is going to create style properties on the id you have selected. 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: but I have to use the css

Comment: can you explain more? do you wont to change a css file you already have or give style to some id?